# Find constant such that a real function is a repartition function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, functions, probability-distributions

Let $f(x) = k\cos x$, $x \in [\frac {-\pi}2, \frac {\pi}2]$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

I said that for $f$ to be a repartition function then it has to satisfy these conditions:
$f(x) \geq 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1\implies 2k=1\implies k = \frac 12$.

Now I have to determine the distribution function $F_X(x).$ In my text book the answer is:

$$F_X(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}0\;\;,\;x\;\;<\;-\frac{\mathrm\pi}2\\\frac{1+\sin\;x}2,\;-\frac{\mathrm\pi}2\;\leq x<\frac{\mathrm\pi}2\\1,\;x\;\geq\;\frac{\mathrm\pi}2\end{array}\right.$$

But why is that? Couldn't the answer just be:
$$F_X(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}0\;\;,\;x\;\;<\;-\frac{\mathrm\pi}2\\\frac{\cos x}2,\;-\frac{\mathrm\pi}2\;\leq x<\frac{\mathrm\pi}2\\1,\;x\;\geq\;\frac{\mathrm\pi}2\end{array}\right.$$

How would I calculate:
$P(X \in [0, \frac {\pi}4] | X > \frac {\pi}6)$ and $P(X > 0 | X\in [\frac {-\pi}4, \frac {\pi}4])$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $-\frac{\mathrm\pi}2\;\leq x<\frac{\mathrm\pi}2$,
$$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt=0+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^x \cos(t)\, dt=
\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin(t)\right]_{-\pi/2}^x=\frac{1+\sin(x)}2.$$
Moreover, recall that $F_X(x)=P(X\in(-\infty,x])$, and, by definition (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution)), 
$$P(X \in B | X \in A)=\frac{\int_{A\cap B} f(x)\,dx}{\int_{A} f(x)\,dx}.$$
So, for example, 
$$P(X \in [0, \pi/4 | X > \pi/6)=
\frac{\int_{(\pi/6,\pi/4]} f(x)\,dx}{\int_{(\pi/6,+\infty)} f(x)\,dx}=
\frac{F_X(\pi/4)-F_X(\pi/6)}{1-F_X(\pi/6)}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Makes sense now! What about the probabilities?

Comment: Yeah, I know that but why does it help me to $P(X > \frac {\pi}6) = 1 - P(X \leq \frac {\pi}6)$, can't I just integrate from $\frac {\pi}6$ to $\frac {\pi}2$?

Comment: If $B=[0, \frac {\pi}4]$ and $A=(\frac {\pi}6,+\infty)$ then what is $A\cap B$?
No need of integrate. Use $F_X$!!

Comment: Well, $(\frac {\pi}6, \frac {\pi}4)$, also if I had for example $3$ intervals on the function and different functions on each for example , $[a, b]$, $[b, c]$ and $[c, \infty]$. Then I should integrate over $[a, x]$ to get the function in $[a, b]$  and to get the function in $[b, c]$ I should add the function in $[a, b]$ with the result of the intregral of the given function on $[b, x]$ and then for $[c, \infty]$ it would be $1$, right?

Comment: No, no, my question is that, to calculate this, the function is *too* cumulative, just like it was discrete, right? The next interval will always be the last integral + the one you had to on the current interval, right?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I understood that part, but I'm talking for another repartition function

Comment: This procedure is general. Given a repartition function you find the distribution function...